# how do i always show kendo grid default data row at the end of data source angularjs

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, row, datasource

how do i always show a default data entering row at the end of data source in kendo grid ??

i want to have a kendo grid with input row at the grid bottom at all times. when i enter data and press 'enter' key, the data should be inserted in the grid from top  to bottom but the default data entry row should stay at grid bottom.

Below is the grid initialization. i have used angularjs / javascript with kendo grid.

```
    //-> Grid Sample data for demo purposes

        var s1 = [];

        //@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

        //-> Grid Start


        var configAddPaymentsEnter = {};

        configAddPaymentsEnter.resizable = true

        configAddPaymentsEnter.sortable = true;

        configAddPaymentsEnter.pageable = false;
        //{
        //  input: true,
        //  numeric: false
        //   };
        configAddPaymentsEnter.editable =
        {
            createAt: 'bottom'
        };

        configAddPaymentsEnter.columns = [

                {
                    field: "ConnectionReference",
                    attributes: {
                        "navi-text": ""
                    },
                    headerTemplate: 'Connection Reference',
                    template: '<input ng-keydown="AA(this,$event)" type ="text"   ng-model="dataItem.ConnectionReference"  class="k-fill text-right aa" format-number ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?$/"    />',
                    width: "130px"
                    // ,aggregates: ["count"], footerTemplate: "Total Count: #=count#"
                },
                 {
                     field: "ContractNumber",
                     attributes: {
                         "navi-text": ""
                     },
                     headerTemplate: 'Contract Number',
                     template: '<input ng-keydown="AA(this,$event)" type ="text"   class="k-fill text-right aa"  ng-model="dataItem.ContractNumber"  format-number ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?$/"    />',
                     width: "130px"
                 },
                  {
                      field: "Amount",
                      attributes: {
                          "navi-text": ""
                      },
                      headerTemplate: 'Amount',
                      template: '<input ng-keydown="AA(this,$event)" kendo-numeric-text-box type ="text"  class="k-fill text-right aa"  ng-model="dataItem.Amount" format-number ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?$/"    />',
                      width: "130px"

                      // ,aggregates: ["sum"], footerTemplate: "Total Amount: #=sum#"
                  },
                  {
                      field: "ReferenceNumber",
                      attributes: {
                          "navi-text": ""
                      },
                      headerTemplate: 'Reference Number',
                      template: '<input ng-keydown="AA(this,$event)"  type ="text"    class="k-fill text-right aa"  ng-model="dataItem.ReferenceNumber"  format-number ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?$/"    />',
                      width: "130px"
                  }
                  //,
                  //{
                  //    field: "RowIndex",
                  //    attributes: {
                  //        "navi-text": ""
                  //    },
                  //    headerTemplate: 'RowIndex',
                  //    template: '<input ng-keydown="AA(this,$event)"  type ="text"    class="k-fill text-right aa"  ng-model="dataItem.RowIndex"  format-number ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?$/"    />',
                  //    width: "130px"
                  //}
        ];


        configAddPaymentsEnter.scrollable = true;

        configAddPaymentsEnter.dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: [s1],
            //group: {
            //    field: "ConnectionReference", aggregates: [
            //       { field: "ConnectionReference", aggregate: "count" },
            //       { field: "Amount", aggregate: "sum" }
            //    ]
            //},

            //aggregate: [{ field: "ConnectionReference", aggregate: "count" },
            //              { field: "Amount", aggregate: "sum" }],            

            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "ID",
                    fields: {

                        'ConnectionReference': { editable: true, type: "number" },
                        'ContractNumber': { editable: true, type: "number" },
                        'Amount': { editable: true, type: "number" },
                        'ReferenceNumber': { editable: true, type: "number" }
                        //,
                        // 'RowIndex': { editable: false, type: "number" }


                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 5000,

        });

        $scope.dgGridAddPaymentsEnter = new DataGrid();
        $scope.dgGridAddPaymentsEnter.options(configAddPaymentsEnter);

        $scope.Init = function (arg) {
            $scope.dgGridAddPaymentsEnter.Init(arg);
        };
        $scope.Init = function (arg) {
            $scope.dgGridAddPaymentsEnter.Init(arg);
        };
```

Comment: May be you can use grid footer as input row

Answer (score 0):

This 'how to' example would be helpful: 
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Editing/add-row-when-tabbed-out-of-last-row

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Locking option of Kendo Grid UI.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/appearance#locking

But, unfortunately frozen rows are not supported at the moment as far as i know. The best technique would be to include the frozen data in the Grid's footer, and take care of manually syncing any changes (edits) to the data values